# Parse comma- and colon-separated numbers into to array values in Bash script

Tags: bash, shell-script, arguments

I have a Bash script for deploying a service. It needs an update in the form of an additional command line argument for specifying ports for launching multiple instances of the service. The argument accepts comma-separated ports as well as colon-separated ranges of ports, i.e., some valid values are

```
5001,5002,5003,5004
5001:5004
2003,4001:4008
1337,2300:2340,5000,5008
```

These values need to be read into an array, expanding the ranges (i.e., in the case of `2003,4001:4008` the values array should be `[2003,4001,4002,4003,4004,4005,4006,4007,4008]`).

I can't seem to find an efficient way to handle all of these cases using just Bash (Perl is not allowed, awk might be). TIA.

Comment: Are you expecting a JSON array as output? What is the result that you are looking for? Do you want the loop that starts the service, one for each port number?

Comment: > Do you want the loop that starts the service, one for each port number?

Yes, that would be the desired result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a modern `awk` implementation:

```bsh
awk -v RS='[,\n]' -F: 'NF == 1; NF == 2 { for (i = $1; i <= $2; ++i) print i }'
```

The above `awk` command reads a line or set of lines on the format that you describe, and treats each comma-or-newline-separated value as "a record" and each colon-delimited string as "a field".

If a record has a single field (`NF == 1`), it is printed as-is.  This is one of the values in the input that is not a range.

If a record has two fields (`NF == 2`), the numbers in the range from the first field to the second are printed.

Testing:

```bsh
$ echo '2003,4001:4008' | awk -v RS='[,\n]' -F: 'NF == 1; NF == 2 { for (i = $1; i <= $2; ++i) print i }'
2003
4001
4002
4003
4004
4005
4006
4007
4008
```

You may then use this generated list in any way that you want.  For example,

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

printf '%s\n' "$1" |
awk -v RS='[,\n]' -F: 'NF == 1; NF == 2 { for (i = $1; i <= $2; ++i) print i }' |
xargs -I {} some_executable ...options... --port={}
```

This would execute `some_executable ...options... --port={}` once for each outputted number from the `awk` code, with `{}` replaced by the number. The `awk` code gets the string given as the first argument to the script.

No validation of the supplied argument is made.

Answer (score 1):

Since you control the data, we can use parameter and brace expansion. The guard clause added to protect against malicious input, because I'm using unquoted variables and `eval` to achieve the wanted effect.

```bsh
expand() {
    if [[ $1 == *[^,:[:digit:]]* ]]; then
        echo "unexpected characters detected in argument" >&2
        return 1
    fi
    local IFS=,
    for val in $1; do
        if [[ $val == *:* ]]; then
            eval "printf '%s\n' {${val/:/..}}"
        else
            echo "$val"
        fi
    done
}
```

Then, testing with your data:

```bsh
while read line; do
    readarray -t values < <(expand "$line")
    declare -p values
done << 'END'
5001,5002,5003,5004
5001:5004
2003,4001:4008
1337,2300:2340,5000,5008
1,2,3,$(some malicious command),4
END
```

results in

```
declare -a values=([0]="5001" [1]="5002" [2]="5003" [3]="5004")
declare -a values=([0]="5001" [1]="5002" [2]="5003" [3]="5004")
declare -a values=([0]="2003" [1]="4001" [2]="4002" [3]="4003" [4]="4004" [5]="4005" [6]="4006" [7]="4007" [8]="4008")
declare -a values=([0]="1337" [1]="2300" [2]="2301" [3]="2302" [4]="2303" [5]="2304" [6]="2305" [7]="2306" [8]="2307" [9]="2308" [10]="2309" [11]="2310" [12]="2311" [13]="2312" [14]="2313" [15]="2314" [16]="2315" [17]="2316" [18]="2317" [19]="2318" [20]="2319" [21]="2320" [22]="2321" [23]="2322" [24]="2323" [25]="2324" [26]="2325" [27]="2326" [28]="2327" [29]="2328" [30]="2329" [31]="2330" [32]="2331" [33]="2332" [34]="2333" [35]="2334" [36]="2335" [37]="2336" [38]="2337" [39]="2338" [40]="2339" [41]="2340" [42]="5000" [43]="5008")
unexpected characters detected in argument
declare -a values=()
```

Answer (score -2):

```
for j in `cat file`; do echo $j | perl -pne "s/,/\n/g"| awk -F ":" '/:/{for(i=$1;i<=$2;i++)print i}1'|sed '/:/d'| awk 'ORS=" "'; echo -e "\n";done



output

5001 5002 5003 5004 

5001 5002 5003 5004 

2003 4001 4002 4003 4004 4005 4006 4007 4008 

1337 2300 2301 2302 2303 2304 2305 2306 2307 2308 2309 2310 2311 2312 2313 2314 2315 2316 2317 2318 2319 2320 2321 2322 2323
```